# Disproving that if Z-Y is a subset of Z-X then X is a subset of Y

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am tasked with disproving that if $Z-Y \subseteq Z-X$ then $X \subseteq Y$. I've played with some examples but I always end up with X being a subset of Y.

Answer (score 3):

Consider

$$Z=\{1,2,3\},\ Y=\{1,2,4\}\ \text{and}\ X=\{1,5\}.$$
Thus,

$$Z-Y=\{3\}\ \text{and}\ Z-X=\{2,3\}\Rightarrow Z-Y\subset Z-X.$$

However, $X\not\subset Y$, neither $Y\not\subset X$.

Answer (score 3):

Or $Z=Y=\emptyset$ and $X=\{1\}$.

Basically, $Z-Y \subseteq Z-X$ exactly tells you that $Z \cap X \subseteq Z \cap Y$ but that does not tell you anything about what happens outside of $Z$.

So take any $X,Y,Z$ with  $Z-Y \subseteq Z-X$ (such as $X=Y=X=\emptyset)$ and change $X$ to $X'=X \cup \{a\}$ where $a \notin Y \cup Z.$  Then

- $X' \not\subseteq Y$
- $Z-X'=Z-X$ so $Z-Y \subseteq Z-X=Z-X'.$

Comment: I think your answer is more ellegant than mine, I will give a upvote!

Comment: I guess the OP should accept this answer (or the other one). I can't imagine better explanations.